# bounding a $C^1$ function that upholds $f'(t)\leq 1-f(t)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function which is continuously differentiable.

Suppose that $\forall t\in\mathbb{R}$ it holds 
$$f'(t)\leq 1-f(t)^2$$
Prove that $\forall t\in\mathbb{R}:|f(t)|\leq 1$.

I know about some comparison theorems, i.e. if we have a solution (in a compact domain) of the Riccati equation $\dot{x}(t)=1-x(t)^2$, with the same initial value as of $f$, then in this domain we get that $f\leq x$. My problem is that it only gives an upper bound and not a lower bound.

Comment: It says $\dot{f}(t)\leq 1-f(t)^2$, not $f(t)\leq1-f(t)^2$

Comment: Use Grönwall's inequality.

Comment: @uniquesolution But here I only have $f'(t)\leq \Big(\frac{1}{f(t)}-f(t)\Big)\cdot f(t)$

Comment: @user554578 - Are you familiar with the Grönwall's inequality? It allows you to deduce boundedness of functions satisfying differential inequalities, which is what you have here. In fact, your problem is a  standard exercise that comes right after the class in which Grönwall's inequality would have been introduced. Start by solving the corresponding differential equation. (with equality sign).

Comment: @uniquesolution I don't see how to use Grönwall's inequality. By this I mean that from Wikipedia, I see that it supplies an upper bound if we have $f'(t)\leq g(t)f(t)$. Isn't it easier to solve the equation $\dot{x}(t)=1-x(t)^2$ to get the upper bound as it seems to work. But, how can I get a lower bound?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key point to consider is that the domain of the function is demanded to be the whole of $\Bbb R$. The function is not allowed to have poles or other kinds of discontinuities, it has to stay bounded over all finite intervals.

> **Claim:** If $f$ leaves the interval $[-1,1]$, $|f(t_*)|>1$ for some $t_*$, then $f$ has a pole, that is, it has to diverge towards $\pm \infty$ in finite time.

If $f(t_*)<-1$, the function has to be monotonically falling around $t_*$ and keep being falling for $t>t_*$. Then conclude that for $t>t_*$
$$
f'(t)\le -cf(t)^2~~\text{ where }~~c=\frac{f(t_*)^2-1}{f(t_*)^2}
$$
so that
$$
f(t)\le\frac{f(t_*)}{1+cf(t_*)(t-t_*)}
$$
goes to minus infinity in finite time. This contradicts the domain being the whole of $\Bbb R$, so that $f$ has to be bounded on finite intervals.

---

Or put another way, by assumption $f(t)$ is finite and by the general considerations above falling for $t\ge t_*$, so that $f(t)<f(t_*)<-1$. By the mean value theorem one can now conclude
$$
-\frac1{f(t_*)}\ge-\frac1{f(t_*)}+\frac1{f(t)}=-\frac{f'(s)}{f(s)^2}(t-t_*)\ge\left(1-\frac1{f(s)^2}\right)(t-t_*)\ge\left(1-\frac1{f(t_*)^2}\right)(t-t_*)
$$
which is quite impossible as the left side is a positive constant while the right is an unbounded increasing function.

---

The same argument goes for $f(t_*)>1$ looking in direction $-\infty$ and growth towards $+\infty$, since $\tilde f(t)=-f(-t)$ satisfies the same assumptions.

---

#### Added 7/2019: Use the structure of the equality solution

Assume again $f(t_*)<-1$ and consider $$g(t)=\dfrac{f(t)+1}{f(t)-1}=1+\dfrac2{f(t)-1}.$$ At $t=t_*$ we get $g(t_*)\in(0,1)$. It is not possible for $g$ to have the value $1$.

Now consider the derivative and insert the differential inequality 
$$
g'(t)=-\frac{2f'(t)}{(f(t)-1)^2}\ge -2\frac{1-f(t)^2}{(f(t)-1)^2}=2g(t).
$$
By the general Grönwall theory we get for $t>t_*$
$$
g(t)\ge e^{2(t-t_*)}g(t_*).
$$
This grows unbounded and thus has to cross the value $1$. At that point $f$ must have a singularity.